# Use different style sheets in web view on iOS 7 or 8

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, webview

I have an app which uses a WebView to display text and images. On iOS 8, I have set the margin and padding to 0px to correctly layout the HTML page. However to view correctly on iOS 7, the margin and padding have to be set to 4px.

How can i have it so that it has the two different formats for both iOS versions.

I want it to automatically have the padding and margin set to 0px on iOS 8 and 4px on iOS 7. This is my current stylesheet (which is in an NSString).

```
   NSString *stylesheet=@"<html><head><style>body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }h1{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 3px;}p{font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; padding-top:0px; padding-left: 7px;paddin-right: 7px; margin-top:10px;}imgcenter {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}b{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Medium;}</style></head><body>";
    NSString *footer=@"</body></html>";

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",stylesheet, self.SelectedProduct.content, footer];
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [_webview loadHTMLString:fullURL baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use CSS Media Queries to get the correct effect? See http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: Thanks for your help. While I have solved the problem using a different method, your link has helped to solve a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to sort it out using if statements and checking the system version.

Heres the working code

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)                  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)              ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)                 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
          NSString *stylesheet=@"<html><head><style>body { margin: 4px; padding: 4px; margin-top:0px}h1{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 3px; padding-top:0px;}p{font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; padding-top:0px; padding-left: 7px;paddin-right: 7px; margin-top:10px;}imgcenter {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}b{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Medium;}</style></head><body>";
        NSString *footer=@"</body></html>";

        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",stylesheet, self.SelectedProduct.content, footer];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        [_webview loadHTMLString:fullURL baseURL:baseURL];
    }

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
          NSString *stylesheet=@"<html><head><style>body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; margin-top:0px}h1{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin; padding: 7px; margin-bottom: 3px; }p{font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; padding-top:0px; padding-left: 7px;paddin-right: 7px; margin-top:10px;}imgcenter {display: block; margin: 0 auto;}b{font-weight:normal;font-family: HelveticaNeue-Medium;}</style></head><body>";
        NSString *footer=@"</body></html>";

        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",stylesheet, self.SelectedProduct.content, footer];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        [_webview loadHTMLString:fullURL baseURL:baseURL];
    }
```